Python Apply function to create new rows in loop
Goal: Here is a sample of a dataset that has "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS", "MULTI_FACTOR", "DAY_COUNTER", and "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT". The goal is to take every "ID", "PHASENAME", "CDAYS" and increase the "DAY_COUNTER" from whatever the last day is increase it to 100 days. I am also to repeat this for "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT".
currently



ID
PHASENAME
C_DAYS
Multi_Factor
DAY_COUNTER
DAILY_LABOR_%




BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
1
1.0


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
2
5.0


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
13
4.0


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
14
0.0



need it to be



ID
PHASENAME
C_DAYS
Multi_Factor
DAY_COUNTER
DAILY_LABOR_%




BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
1
.14


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
2
some number


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
99
some number


BAR
C
14.0
7.142857
100
0.0



In this sample dataset, this person worked for 14 days and their labor percentage is recorded for each day. Instead of have 14 days of labor, I want to have 100 days of labor ( formulas: 'DAY_COUNTER' * 'Multi_Factor' and "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT" / 'Multi_Factor ).
Also, I'm worried that once I enlarge this dataset having the range as 100 won't work.
Looking for

The Labor is repeating. So when I apply my logic I am not getting the true labor percentage.
Suggestions on how to approach this with a larger dataset.

code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data={
    "ID": [ "BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR","BAR"],
    "PHASENAME": [ "C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C","C"],
    "C_DAYS": [ 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0],
    "Multi_Factor": [7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857, 7.142857],
    "DAY_COUNTER": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
    "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT": [1.0,5.0,9.0,11.0,10.0,9.0,9.0,9.0,8.0,10.0,8.0,7.0,4.0,0.0],
    }

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df1=df.copy()


n = 100
first_day = df["DAY_COUNTER"].iloc[0]

rep = np.tile(df.values, (n // len(df) + 1, 1))
out = pd.DataFrame(rep, columns=df.columns).iloc[:n]

out["DAY_COUNTER"] = range(first_day, n + first_day)


def labor_factor(row):
    return row['DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT'] / row['Multi_Factor']

#creating empty list to store rows for each id, phasename, and cdays
new_rows= []

#iterating through each index range and applying function to get day_counter to 100

for i in range(len(out)):
    out['new_labor']= out.apply(labor_factor,axis=1)



Please show the full traceback of the error.

The value of row is not a row, it's the string BAR.

@Barmar I’m not sure if I’m understanding. I thought that my math function could create a new value and the iteration would have created new rows for that value in the new dataset.

The problem is how you're passing the arguments to the function. .apply() isn't passing the entire row, it's just passing one value.

I think you may be confusing how Pandas.DataFrame.apply and Pandas.Series.apply work. .iloc returns a series.

@Barmar I updated my for loop to  new_row= df1.apply(day_factor,axis=1) and it worked

What happened to i % len(df1)?

As a general rule, you want to avoid iterating over dataframe rows, as that's very inefficient.
IIUC, you can instead repeat your dataframe using something vectorized like numpy.tile until you have the desired number of rows, then adjust the values accordingly:
n = 100
first_day = df["DAY_COUNTER"].iloc[0]

rep = np.tile(df.values, (n // len(df) + 1, 1))
out = pd.DataFrame(rep, columns=df.columns).iloc[:n]

out["DAY_COUNTER"] = range(first_day, n + first_day)

     ID PHASENAME C_DAYS Multi_Factor  DAY_COUNTER DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT
0   BAR         C   14.0     7.142857            1                 1.0
1   BAR         C   14.0     7.142857            2                 5.0
2   BAR         C   14.0     7.142857            3                 9.0
3   BAR         C   14.0     7.142857            4                11.0
4   BAR         C   14.0     7.142857            5                10.0
..  ...       ...    ...          ...          ...                 ...
95  BAR         C   14.0     7.142857           96                 7.0
96  BAR         C   14.0     7.142857           97                 4.0
97  BAR         C   14.0     7.142857           98                 0.0
98  BAR         C   14.0     7.142857           99                 1.0
99  BAR         C   14.0     7.142857          100                 5.0


Where is the multiplication by Multi_Factor?

@Barmar it's not needed to "get day_counter to 100".

@e-motta thanks, for teaching me about numpy tile and for the refresher about for loops. However, now, I am stuck with expanding the "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT". Right now, the labor is repeating. I will update my problem and query above.

@Barmar thanks, for teaching me about numpy tile and for the refresher about for loops. However, now, I am stuck with expanding the "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT". Right now, the labor is repeating. I will update my problem and query above.

@TyKendall If you need to divide column 'DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT' proportionately by how much the dataframe was enlarged, you can do out["DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT"] = out["DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT"] / (n / len(df)). n / len(df) in this case is 7.142857, but this way you make it dynamic and don't need to store a repeated value in another column.

@e-motta Thanks. I believe that since the days is being expanded the labor % should be expanded as well. In DF, the % goes up and down depending on the day. So I thought the Multi_Factor, would help expand it out.  I'll play around with the equation that you gave me.

@TyKendall I'm going with what you explained in the question: "DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT" / 'Multi_Factor'. This would be dividing the percentages by the same factor the dataframe was enlarged, in this case 7.142857. Which is what out["DAILY_LABOR_PERCENT"] / (n / len(df)) will do.
